# Custom webform element does not pass custom properties to $element array

Tags: webforms

I made custom @WebformElement , all good, expect new custom property check_if_work which I defined in defineDefaultProperties() and $form['validation']['check_if_work'] of form() is not present in prepare() $element. What could be the reason?
I was examining the pattern property of abstract class TextBase extends WebformElementBase and I see no difference, but mine check_if_work is null (not present in $element array)

Aked that on slack - no luck https://drupal.slack.com/archives/C78MFLN9K/p1695048527776959

Webform v 6.1.4

Comment: Include the custom code in the Question.